# How can I have a query with GROUP_CONCAT return more the one row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, group-concat

```
TXNID                PARENT_TXN_ID      ITEM_NAME

5G161631H9141883L                       Merchandise Total
4HD251984H4919123                       Woodworking 101@Fri 04-05-2013 8:00 pm
4LA48638GR031562M                       Woodworking 101@Fri 04-05-2013 8:00 pm
6TU64611FM249252D                       Woodworking 101@Fri 04-05-2013 8:00 pm
7S953179AV7967542                       Woodworking 101@Fri 04-05-2013 8:00 pm
04916720G2800071A                       Woodworking 101@Fri 04-05-2013 8:00 pm
test1               4HD251984H4919123   setet
```

the above is my data.
here is my query.

```
SELECT ppv1.*,GROUP_CONCAT(ppv2.txn_id SEPARATOR ' <BR>') GC 
from paypal_valid ppv1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT txn_id,parent_txn_id from paypal_valid where parent_txn_id!='')
ppv2 ON ppv1.txn_id=ppv2.parent_txn_id
where ppv1.item_name!='Merchandise Total' and ppv1.parent_txn_id=''
```

This is only returning 1 row...I'm thinking it should return 5. I'm just not sure why there is only one row being returned.

Comment: you don't have a `GROUP BY`, so the `GROUP_CONCAT` just groups together _every_ result row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this with `group by`

```
 SELECT ppv1.*,GROUP_CONCAT(ppv2.txn_id SEPARATOR ' <BR>') GC 
 from paypal_valid ppv1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT txn_id,parent_txn_id from paypal_valid where parent_txn_id!='')
 ppv2 ON ppv1.txn_id=ppv2.parent_txn_id
where ppv1.item_name!='Merchandise Total' and ppv1.parent_txn_id=''
group by ppv1.txn_id
                ^^^-------//make sure u have this in your ppv1 table
```